# Why can't my Github Action read the last command line argument? But my PC works fine

Tags: python-3.x, github-actions, argv

This is a GitHub Action that will execute a python file in the shell with multiple command line arguments, but the last argument cannot be read.
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChOnD.png)

[the github action result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ofmb1.png)

[my pc result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbEOU.png)

[the action's yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0238Z.png)

Comment: You're using 9 arguments when calling the script in your workflow, but the `sys.argv[9]` actually takes the 10th, as the count start at `sys.argv[0]` for the first one.

Comment: But in Python's arguments, the first is the name of the script, i.e. "sys.argv[0]" is the name of the script。You can see the result of the second picture

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by GuiFalourd, your script uses array from 1 to 9, where it should use 0 to 8 : `sys.argv[0] ... sys.argv[8]`

Comment: thanks，but in Python's arguments, the first is the name of the script, i.e. "sys.argv[0]" is the name of the script。You can see the result of the second picture